# (Expected @AndroidEntryPoint to have a value. Did you forget to apply the Gradle Plugin? ) Using dagger hilt with PESDK

Tags: android, kotlin, photoeditorsdk, dagger-hilt

I am using dagger hilt with PESDK (Photo editor sdk) [GIT](https://github.com/imgly/pesdk-android-demo)
[Photo Editor SDK](https://docs.photoeditorsdk.com/guides/android/v7_6/introduction/overview)

Error

```
 Expected @AndroidEntryPoint to have a value. Did you forget to apply the Gradle Plugin?
```

Everything was building fine before adding dependencies and changing what PESDK required to set it up

Comment: Please provide more code. Did you @Inject PESDK? Have you annotated your Activity and Fragment with @AndroidEntryPoint? Please follow https://dagger.dev/hilt/

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Yes , sorry I forgot to update here. I was using new dagger hilt and it required @AndroidEntryPoint wherever an Injection is required in Fragment. I was using the annotation in wrong place. Also I updated to latest dependencies